# Shutdown of Facebook app because of unauthorized api requests

Tags: facebook, api, shutdown

One of my apps can be installed on Facebook pages (tabs).

Users do not need to authenticate it because the app does not need any user related information.

But I do need the name, profile_url and thumbnail_url of pages that install the app. 
I fetch this information via FQL.

I can see in my log files that some of my api request to retrieve this information fail with a message like "you are not authorized to access this information", probably because these pages are restricted.

Unfortunately there is no way to know in advance if I can access this information or if the request will fail.

My question is: can this ever be a problem on Facebook's side, might their automated systems shut down my app for that?

Answer (score 7):

our automated systems are primarily concerned with making the user experience great, so the answer is no.